# Why should the conical flask (apparatus on the right) used in Fractional Distillation be left open (without a bung)?

Tags: distillation

With context to the image shown, is there a reason as to why the conical flask shouldn't be closed with a bung and is there a way to describe this error?

[image]

Comment: Who said  the receiving flask *should* be closed? What "*error*" are you talking about? Sure, for the distillation of, say, nitric acid, the receiving flask is connected with an adapter and a gas outlet, but there is no need to do so for the non-volatile fractions.

Comment: Also, you forgot about [attributing](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) the [illustration](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fractional_distillation_lab_apparatus.svg).

Comment: There needs to be a release in the system somewhere otherwise you are heating a closed system and that is not a good idea. Another problem is using a Bunsen burner for this.

Comment: If you want to find "errors" one is the lack of a fire spreader or a bath and perhaps the lack of some piece of glass or pomix within the liquid to be distilled.

Comment: If a bung does close the flask, the pressure inside the apparatus will grow. The bung will soon or later explode.

Comment: @Maurice - well, you hope the bung explodes and not the glassware...

Answer (score 1):

**Many of the details in the that diagram are obsolete but the lack of a bung is not one of them**

This is probably a very old illustration. Many aspects have been uncommon for decades. Bunsen burners are rarely used in labs now (too unsafe where volatile solvents are present). Most modern apparatus uses ground glass joints not rubber bungs for connections between components. And the specific types of flasks are irrelevant (it doesn't need to be a conical collector flask, for example).

But the lack of a bung on the collector is *important* whatever type of flask is used. The reason is simple: you don't want pressure to build up. The diagram shows a fractional distillation *at atmospheric pressure* and that means you have to leave the system open to the atmosphere. A bung would prevent that meaning that, as the system was heated, pressure would build, the distillation might not even happen and, worse, something would explode.